# angular2-select does not using formcontrol

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am using angular 2-select.

I am using formControlName.

```html
 <form class="edit" [formGroup]="addcameraForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addcameraForm.value)" class="form-horizontal">    
    <div class="albumname">
       <label for="input01">Select user</label>
       <ng-select  style="color:#000;"
           formControlName="selectMultiple"
           [options]="options"
           [multiple]="true"
           placeholder="Select Assets">
      </ng-select>
   </div>             
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <button class="btn btn-success btn-auth" [disabled]="!addcameraForm.valid">Add Camera</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Here is my component.

```html
ngOnInit() {
    this.addcameraForm = this.fb.group({
            ACCESS_USERS : this.fb.array([]),
            APART_ID:[''],
            CAMERA_ACCESS_CODE:[''],
            CAMERA_ACCESS_URL: [''],
            CAMERA_CODE: [''],
            CAMERA_NAME: [''],
            CAMERA_PASSWORD:[''],
            CAMERA_STATUS:[''],
            CAMERA_USERNAME:[''],
            selectMultiple:['']
        });
 }
```

I am getting this err

```html
Error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: 'selectMultiple'
```

How can i fixed this issue.

Kindly advice me,

Answer (score 6):

Try this:-

```
<ng-select  style="color:#000;"
    [formControl]="addcameraForm.controls['selectMultiple']"
    [options]="options"
    [multiple]="true"
    placeholder="Select Assets">
</ng-select>
```

Comment: Welcome! Please select the answers.

Comment: how to select default value in angular2-select